# Given $G,L \leq S_4$, if $|G| = |L| = 6$, do we have $L \cong G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I've been battling at this for a bit, $S_4$ isn't cyclic so that makes things a bit more difficult. I know by Lagrange a subgroup G with order 6 exists. I actually found some examples. Then found by research that each order 6 group is precisely the $S_3$. I'm failing to see why this is important, hence failing to prove the actual headline of this question. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "I know by Lagrange a subgroup $G$ with order $6$ exists." - Lagrange doesn't allow you to conclude this. Instead, deduce the existence of a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$ by considering the set of elements of $S_4$ that fix a particular point.

Comment: You're right, I just worked through the notes and I found that I was very accustomed to using the fundamental theorem of cyclic subgroups in conjunction with Lagrange. Thanks so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two groups of order 6, up to isomorphism: $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Is it possible for a subgroup of $S_4$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Hint: Think about the orders of elements of $S_4$.

Comment: So if I pick the generated group <{$(23),(123)$}> for example, I built something of order 6 (lcm of cycle lengths) right? And it's cyclic and finite, hence isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_6$. But to generalise, if I choose any two elements in $S_4$ such that the cycle lengths of each element is 2 and 3 respectively, this is also isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}_6$. Am I on the right track or not really?

Comment: @Florian Suess Careful! The order of the element $(2 3)(1 2 3)$ is not 6. The order of an element of a symmetric group is the LCM of the cycle lengths of its *disjoint cycle decomposition*. Can you see how in fact *no* element of $S_4$ is of order 6? Therefore a subgroup of $S_4$ of order 6 can not be cyclic, and so it must be isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: Oh... yes that's right, cyclic by definition is a group generated by a single element and lcm of the disjoint cycle decomposition determines the order. Indeed, there is no way for a subgroup of $S_4$ to be cyclic if it has order 6. There simply aren't big enough permutations. Now I'm puzzled on, how can we jump to the conclusion, given a subgroup of G such that it's order is 6, it must be isomorphic to $S_3$, is it the only non-cyclic group of order 6?

Comment: Indeed! And yes, that’s it - a non cyclic group of order 6 is isomorphic to $S_3$. You can find a nice proof of that result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511511/there-are-2-groups-of-order-6-up-to-isomorphism).

Comment: You have been incredibly helpful, you're answer has been perfect and I'm sure if people see this post they'll be able to follow how to solve this question. I wish you the best.